# Why is Dockware's watch-storefront so slow?

Tags: docker, shopware6

I'm using Dockware in order to learn Shopware theme development. When using the "make watch-storefront" command in the container, chromium is downloaded. Even though it is only 142MB it takes a loooong long time to finish.

Does anyone know why that is or how I speed this up?

Comment: That sounds like something you should ask the Shopware guys

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert in dockware setup, but there is an environment variable you may use to avoid downloading of chromium:

export PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=1

(again I admit I would not know how to pass this correctly into dockware)

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna keep that in mind and give it a try when it slows down again.